# Silverlight PivotViewer application doesnt display when deployed to IIS

Tags: windows, silverlight, iis, pivotviewer

I am trying to deploy my *PivotViewer* files to an IIS server. I have added a MIME info for the cxml, dzc and dzi as "text/xml".

What else do I need to do? Currently, if I try to run my PivotViewer app in Visual Studio it is fine.

when I try to access this machine through the IIS webserver, the pivotviewer "loading" page comes up, but the collection never loads.

Comment: Do you keep getting the loading page or just a blank page?

Comment: the loading page. Does this tool have to be run on an IIS server? Can I just link to the cxml on another server(regardless of what that is) or does all the content have to be on the same one?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Same issue here, works fine on IIS Express on local machine but not when published. I can bring up CXML fine but get never ending loading animation...

Answer (score 0):

Enter the full path for the .cxml and look what error you get from there. I struggled with the same error yesterday and tried different options. Started with `Internal Server Error 500` and ended with `Handler "CXML" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list`

Things to try:

- check the `AppPool` (for me it was set to .NET Classic and started working when I set it to `ASP.NET v4.0`)
- Add the mime types (not only `.cxml` but `.dzc` and `.dzi` as well)
- check the ASP.NET installation

> run
>   %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe
>   –i

I blogged about this with links in here: http://silverlight.riiul.com/2011/02/15/handler-cxml-has-a-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-its-module-list/

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the Loading Fail event and look at the exception?

```
PivotViewer.CollectionLoadingFailed += new EventHandler< CollectionErrorEventArgs >( PivotViewer_CollectionLoadingFailed );
```

Answer (score 0):

For other people that may come across this: I was never able to get it to work on IIS7 correctly, I could get it working on my local machine on IIS Express, but never on production.

My solution was to upgrade to Silverlight 5, and use the new Pivot viewer control. It works a lot better, has a number of more features, and no problems in deployment to IIS 7 or 7.5